# i get this error when i run my code "Error report - ORA-00902: invalid datatype 00902. 00000 - "invalid datatype" *Cause: *Action:"

Tags: oracle11g, ddl

This is `project_submissions` database script:

```
create table project_submissions
    ( project_id varchar2 (5),
    component_submitted varchar (250),
    date_submitted TIMESTAMP,
    constraint (PROJECT_ID)FOREIGN KEY, Project_description (PROJECT_ID)
    );
```

this is my table desc for project_description

```
Name            Null?    Type         
--------------- -------- ------------ 
PROJECT_ID      NOT NULL VARCHAR2(5)  
SUPERVISOR_ID            VARCHAR2(5)  
PROJECT_TITLE            VARCHAR2(25) 
PROJECT_SUMMARY          VARCHAR2(25)
```

Comment: Your foreign key syntax is completely wrong

Comment: constraint fk_projectID FOREIGN KEY(PROJECT_ID) references project_description (PROJECT_ID) CORRECT SYNTAX FOR FOREIGN KEY